# Displaying JSON Javascript object from Github to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm pulling JSON from GitHub, turning it into a JS object, and displaying it to HTML. So far I have the first two parts, but I cannot figure out how to display it. Lines 70-73 are my current attempt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>json</title>
    <script>
        function populateHeader(company) {
            const myH1 = document.createElement('h1');
            myH1.textContent = company['companyName'];
            header.appendChild(myH1);

            const myPara = document.createElement('p');
            myPara.textContent = 'Division: ' + company['division'] + ', ' + company['location'] + '\nHead: ' + company['divisionHeadName'];

            header.appendChild(myPara);
        }

        function showEmp(company) {
            const emps = company['members'];

            for (let i = 0; i < emps.length; i++) {
                const myArticle = document.createElement('article');
                const myH2 = document.createElement('h2');
                const myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
                const myList = document.createElement('ul');

                myH2.textContent = emps[i].name + ', ' + emps[i].gender;
                myPara1.textContent = 'Age: ' + emps[i].age + ", Favorite Fruit: " + emps[i].favoriteFruit + ", Contacts:";

                const contacts = emps[i].contacts;
                for (let j = 0; j < contacts.length; j++) {
                    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = emps[j].name + ", " + emps[j].company;
                    myList.appendChild(listItem);
                }

                myArticle.appendChild(myH2);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara1);
                myList.appendChild(listItem);

                section.appendChild(myArticle);
            }
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="hdr">
    </header>

    <section id="sct">
    </section>

    <script>
        const header = document.querySelector('header');
        const section = document.querySelector('section');

        let requestURL = 'https://github.com/drgap/json_example/blob/main/company.jsonhttps://github.com/drgap/json_example/blob/af5d92bc9ed1b399aabdc50b132f51324025facd/company.json';
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', requestURL);
        request.responseType = 'json';
        request.send();

        request.onload = function () {
            const company = request.response;
            populateHeader(company);
            showEmp(company);
        }

        header = header.toString();
        section = section.toString();
        document.getElementById("hdr").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(header);
        document.getElementById("sct").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(section);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tried JSON.stringify on multiple objects to attempt to get it to display.  Expected to get full display of JSON in HTML page.  Received blank page or "null".

Comment: Is that `requestUrl` a typo you passed into StackOverflow or is that what you're using?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/drgap/json_example/blob/main/company.json is not a JSON document, it's an HTML page references a JSON file in a repo. You need to use the "raw" URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drgap/json_example/main/company.json

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in the code. When something does not work as expected in an HTML page, I suggest opening the console in Chrome to read through the errors, which are printed in red, and will give you detailed information about what's wrong.

First issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

This is telling that the line `header = header.toString()` is wrong. As the error message points out, `header` is a constant and therefore its value cannot be updated. Same goes for `section`. You can fix this by declaring `header` with

```
let header = document.querySelector('header');
```

Second issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://github.com/drgap/json_example/blob/af5d92bc9ed1b399aabdc50b132f51324025facd/company.json'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

This is a CORS error. Short explanation, because of the way GitHub set up the resources on their servers you cannot fetch them from a different website, because the domain is different. You're probably making the request from localhost, therefore the error. I strongly suggest to research into CORS, it's not very intuitive for begginers and a thorough understanding of that topic will save you a lot of swear words and effort in the future. Luckily you can get around this issue with the next point.

Third issue: the URL does not provide JSON content, but a page with a sections that shows JSON content. Open the URL you're using and you will notice that it takes you to a full blown web page, not just JSON content. As someone pointed out in comments, you can get the actual content of the file using the raw resource. Replace the raw URL and see how it fixes the problem.

Fourth issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: header.appendChild is not a function

In order to understand this point, you must have clear in mind how JS executes code. You have an `XMLHttpRequest` along with a call to its `send` member. The key here is that `send` is asynchronous. Imagine: your code has tons of things to do and it sends out a request to an external website that will take maybe a second to generate a response. Why on earth would JS need to wait for the response? In fact it doesn't, after sending the request it goes on executing the code to avoid wasting time in the second waiting for the response. This means that the line `header = header.toString()` is executed before the response of the request is received. Therefore, by the time you call `populateHeader` and do `header.appendChild`, the `header` variable will already be a string. A string clearly doesn't have a member called `appendChild` which is a function. How do we fix this?  I really encourage to look into asynchronous operations in JS. In the meanwhile, you can just put the last four lines inside the request call back (i.e., the `request.onload` block).

Next and fifth issue:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: listItem is not defined

`listItem` is only defined inside a `for` loop of the `showEmp` function. When you define a variable inside a loop, it exists within the loop and not anywhere else. Therefore, JS doesn't know what `listItem` is outside the for. But you're still refer to it, hence the error.

Sixth:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'name')

Take a look at the line where this error is thrown and you'll find out that you're doing `emps[j]`, whereas at the beginning you were doing `emps[i]`. I assume this is just an oversight.

After we fix all of this, the console is going to be clean without any errors, but I guess the page is still not looking as you imagined it would. It just shows two strings `"[object HTMLElement]"`. Can you guess why?

I will not provide the full working code to this. It's much, much more useful for you to go through all of these errors one by one and understand what's happening for each and every of them. Have fun and good luck with this!